# I did 3 runs of the same experiment, one of runs has all zeros for both treatments being compared. Can I pool these runs?

Tags: anova

There are 2 treatments, 1) plant A grown in monoculture and 2) plant A grown with plant B. RCBD design. Using ANOVAs to compare reproductive (flower) mass (continuous), least significant difference comparisons between treatments. 3 runs of experiment. One of runs had no flowers produced in any Plant A for either treatment. Do I combine results from run with all zeros, to other 2 runs (which have zero values but also above 0)? Or exclude the run and pool runs with non-zero data?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Greenhouse Experiment! Your question is temporarily closed (not by me, but I would have voted to close, too. A post is reviewed by at least 3 experienced users before it is closed). I find it very hard to understand what you are asking. It seems that you want to exclude a run where you got outcome  equal to 0 from your analysis, or you just don't know what to do about it. / /  How many replications (outcomes) per treatment do you have in each run? is it just one run where you got 0 for 1) and 0 for 2), and the other runs are some number >0 in1), some other number > 0 in 2)?